# How do I reference 2 controls if I am only allowed to have one telerik:RadAjaxManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have 2 panels that I want to use one is `pnlUserInfo` and One is `pnlMedOrders`. I was able to successfully add pnlUserInfo but I cannot figure out how to add the other. Here is my code for `pnlUserInfo`:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="pnlUserInfo">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlUserInfo" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Height="75px"
Width="75px" IsSticky="true" MinDisplayTime="500"> 
<img alt="Loading..." src='<%= RadAjaxLoadingPanel.GetWebResourceUrl(Page,     
"Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.Default.Ajax.loading.gif") %>' style="border: 0px;" />
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The issue with the panels is that you only need one. Currently I have my entire dnn module wrapped in one panel and I have the ajax manager using that instead of `pnlUserInfo` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Make another `AjaxSetting` element in your markup, like this:

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="pnlMedOrders"> 
    <UpdatedControls> 
        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlMedOrders" 
                                    LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" /> 
    </UpdatedControls> 
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

> Note: Both panels share the same loading panel.

---

So your markup should look like this:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="pnlUserInfo">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlUserInfo" 
                                        LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="pnlMedOrders"> 
            <UpdatedControls> 
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlMedOrders" 
                                        LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" /> 
            </UpdatedControls> 
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" 
                             Height="75px" Width="75px" IsSticky="true" 
                             MinDisplayTime="500"> 
    <img alt="Loading..." 
         src='<%= RadAjaxLoadingPanel.GetWebResourceUrl(Page, "Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.Default.Ajax.loading.gif") %>' 
         style="border: 0px;" />
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```

Comment: When I did this it killed my postbacks...i will try it again...i could have done something wrong